# Should No in the definition of Big -oh have to be the intersection of the two curves?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

[image]

In the image above, It is obvious that *n<sub>0</sub>* is positive. Let's suppose
`f(n)=3n+2` and `g(n)=n`.

By the definition of Big-omega `f(n)>=cg(n) => 3n+2>=cn`.

The above two lines `f(n)=3n+2` and `g(n)=n` intersect at `n=-1` in the third quadrant of the co-ordinate axis.

Why would  I have to consider the intersection If I could find out that the above inequality holds true for `c=1` and *n<sub>0</sub> = 1*.

In the above case, *n<sub>0</sub>* was not the intersection in the positive quadrant.
Can I pick any positive value for *n<sub>0</sub>* so that the inequality gets satisfied or should *n<sub>0</sub>* always be the intersection?

Comment: It's unclear how this is a programming question.  This looks like it should belong on [math.se].

Comment: The intersection is not relevant.  In fact, it's only defined for *specific* values of the constant `c`.   The definition of Big-O that you're referring to allows you to choose any values >0 for `c` and `n0`.  It helps to think of n0 as "very large"

Answer (score 1):

Think of *n<sub>0</sub>* as the **breakaway point** such that for all *n* > *n<sub>0</sub>*, you are guaranteed Ω(*f*) > Ω(*cg*). This is important for understanding failure cases in some algorithms. In the above plot, I can see that there are some data volume sizes less than *n<sub>0</sub>* where function *g*() offers superior performance.

Let's consider it with a pointed example. Suppose `g()` is *BubbleSort* and `f()` is *RadixSort* (and we'll assume *K*-bit integers for this example). In this case, *n<sub>0</sub>*=*K*: For all sets with length *n*<*K*, BubbleSort actually performs better in the best-case than RadixSort!

Now, lets suppose I really messed up the implementation of BubbleSort in some way (or that I'm running multiple instances of it in parallel). Then, as long as *cn* < *K*, then Ω(*cg*) < Ω(*f*).